# Pass arguments to Constructor in VBA

Tags: vba, class, oop, constructor, factory

How can you construct objects passing arguments directly to your own classes?

Something like this:

```
Dim this_employee as Employee
Set this_employee = new Employee(name:="Johnny", age:=69)
```

Not being able to do this is very annoying, and you end up with dirty solutions to work this around.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67825/parameterised-constructors

Comment: For Immutability a Private Init and a Factory inside the class can be used: [Private VBA Class Initializer called from Factory](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253233/private-vba-class-initializer-called-from-factory-2)

Comment: Follow-up on the above comment. The Private Class initializer is now supported on GitHub within this [repo](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools). Method is called ```RedirectInstance``` and needs to be called from a Private Function. In conjunction with a Class Factory the immutability is achieved.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Here's a little trick I'm using lately and brings good results. I would like to share with those who have to fight often with VBA.

**1.-** Implement a public initiation subroutine in each of your custom classes. I call it InitiateProperties throughout all my classes. This method has to accept the arguments you would like to send to the constructor.

**2.-** Create a module called factory, and create a public function with the word "Create" plus the same name as the class, and the same incoming arguments as the constructor needs. This function has to instantiate your class, and call the initiation subroutine explained in point (1), passing the received arguments. Finally returned the instantiated and initiated method.

Example:

Let's say we have the custom class Employee. As the previous example, is has to be instantiated with name and age.

This is the InitiateProperties method. m_name and m_age are our private properties to be set.

```
Public Sub InitiateProperties(name as String, age as Integer)

    m_name = name
    m_age = age

End Sub
```

And now in the factory module:

```
Public Function CreateEmployee(name as String, age as Integer) as Employee

    Dim employee_obj As Employee
    Set employee_obj = new Employee

    employee_obj.InitiateProperties name:=name, age:=age
    set CreateEmployee = employee_obj

End Function
```

And finally when you want to instantiate an employee

```
Dim this_employee as Employee
Set this_employee = factory.CreateEmployee(name:="Johnny", age:=89)
```

Especially useful when you have several classes. Just place a function for each in the module factory and instantiate just by calling **factory.CreateClassA(arguments)**, **factory.CreateClassB(other_arguments)**, etc.

## EDIT

As stenci pointed out, you can do the same thing with a terser syntax by avoiding to create a local variable in the constructor functions. For instance the CreateEmployee function could be written like this:

```
Public Function CreateEmployee(name as String, age as Integer) as Employee

    Set CreateEmployee = new Employee
    CreateEmployee.InitiateProperties name:=name, age:=age

End Function
```

Which is nicer.

Comment: Nice solution! Though I would probably rename it `factory.CreateEmployee` to reduce ambiguity...

Comment: Yes you're right, it would be less ambiguous. Although I got used to read "factory." as if it was "new". I'll change it.

Comment: What's the benefit of a factory module over, say, a Construct method in each class.  So you would call `Set employee_obj = New Employee` then `employee_obj.Construct "Johnny", 89` and the construction stuff happens inside the class.  Just curious.

Comment: Hi, I see some benefits. It can be that they overlap somewhat. First of all, you use a constructor in a standard way like you would in any normal OOP language, which enhances clarity. Then, each time you instantiate an object, you save that line to initiate your object which makes you write less, then you CANNOT forget to initialize the object, and finally there is one concept less on your procedure, which reduces complexity.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure the .InitiateProperties() is never called a second time on the same object?

With a constructor this is automatically the case, because you construct an object only once. The 'init' method makes your object mutable, even if you don't want it to be mutable. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: You can keep track of it with a private variable. You can define `Class_Initialize`, and then define there a variable `m_initialized = false`. When you enter the `InitiateProperties`, you check the `m_initialized` and if it is false, continue and at the end, set it to true. If it is true, raise an error or do nothing. If you call again the InitiateProperties method, it will be true and the state of the object won't be changed.

Comment: Sorry to wake this up from the dead, but that last paragraph is wrong, that is *not* "nicer" code. Treating a function's return mechanism (assign to identifier) as a declared local variable is misleading and confusing *at best*, not "nicer" (*looks* like a recursive call, doesn't it?). If you want terser syntax, leverage module attributes as illustrated in my answer. As a bonus you lose that *Single-Responsibility-Principle-takes-a-beating* "factory bag" module responsible for creating instances of just about everything and its mother and inevitably becomes a mess in any decent-size project.

Comment: @CodeKid see my answer below for an actual solution to these problems. Immutability is achieved by coding against an interface that doesn't expose the setters that the factory method invokes.

Comment: @Mat'sMug it's been a long time since I last wrote a VBA line, so maybe this has changed meanwhile, but at least when I wrote this, that was the standard (and crappy) way of returning values from functions. You could create another variable and assign it at the end to the function's name, but under the hood you are doing exactly the very same thing.

Answer (score 47):

I use one `Factory` module that contains one (or more) *constructor* per class which calls the `Init` member of each class.

For example a `Point` class:

```
Class Point
Private X, Y
Sub Init(X, Y)
  Me.X = X
  Me.Y = Y
End Sub
```

A `Line` class

```
Class Line
Private P1, P2
Sub Init(Optional P1, Optional P2, Optional X1, Optional X2, Optional Y1, Optional Y2)
  If P1 Is Nothing Then
    Set Me.P1 = NewPoint(X1, Y1)
    Set Me.P2 = NewPoint(X2, Y2)
  Else
    Set Me.P1 = P1
    Set Me.P2 = P2
  End If
End Sub
```

And a `Factory` module:

```
Module Factory
Function NewPoint(X, Y)
  Set NewPoint = New Point
  NewPoint.Init X, Y
End Function

Function NewLine(Optional P1, Optional P2, Optional X1, Optional X2, Optional Y1, Optional Y2)
  Set NewLine = New Line
  NewLine.Init P1, P2, X1, Y1, X2, Y2
End Function

Function NewLinePt(P1, P2)
  Set NewLinePt = New Line
  NewLinePt.Init P1:=P1, P2:=P2
End Function

Function NewLineXY(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
  Set NewLineXY = New Line
  NewLineXY.Init X1:=X1, Y1:=Y1, X2:=X2, Y2:=Y2
End Function
```

One nice aspect of this approach is that makes it easy to use the factory functions inside expressions. For example it is possible to do something like:

```
D = Distance(NewPoint(10, 10), NewPoint(20, 20)
```

or:

```
D = NewPoint(10, 10).Distance(NewPoint(20, 20))
```

It's clean: the factory does very little and it does it consistently across all objects, just the creation and one `Init` call on each *creator*.

And it's fairly object oriented: the `Init` functions are defined inside the objects.

**EDIT**

I forgot to add that this allows me to create static methods. For example I can do something like (after making the parameters optional):

```
NewLine.DeleteAllLinesShorterThan 10
```

Unfortunately a new instance of the object is created every time, so any static variable will be lost after the execution. The collection of lines and any other static variable used in this pseudo-static method must be defined in a module.

Comment: This is cleaner than the selected answer.

Comment: It's been a long time since I last played with VBA, but... **1**: how do you get constructed objects from the `Factory`'s subroutines? the definition of `Sub` entails no return value. **2**: even with the point I am missing, your `Factory`'s do pretty much the same thing as mine: create an object (I do it in two steps, your syntax is clearly shorter), call an `Init`/`InitiateProperties` method, and in my case, explicitly return.

Comment: @ikaros45 They were supposed to be `Function`, not `Sub`, I edited the post, thanks. Yes, it is the same as yours, it's just organized in a way easier to manage (in my opinion) as the number of classes and the number of "constructors" for each class grows.

Comment: Yeap well, the organization is exactly the same, but I agree that your way it's more succint. It means the same but you save two lines per constructor function, which is nice. If you don't mind, I'll update my code with your syntax.

Answer (score 44):

When you export a class module and open the file in Notepad, you'll notice, near the top, a bunch of hidden attributes (the VBE doesn't display them, and doesn't expose functionality to tweak most of them either). One of them is `VB_PredeclaredId`:

```
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
```

Set it to `True`, save, and re-import the module into your VBA project.

Classes with a `PredeclaredId` have a "global instance" that you get for free - exactly like `UserForm` modules (export a user form, you'll see its predeclaredId attribute is set to true).

A lot of people just happily use the predeclared instance to store state. That's wrong - it's like storing instance state in a static class!

Instead, you leverage that default instance to implement your factory method:

[`Employee` class]

```
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private Type TEmployee
    Name As String
    Age As Integer
End Type

Private this As TEmployee

Public Function Create(ByVal emplName As String, ByVal emplAge As Integer) As Employee
    With New Employee
        .Name = emplName
        .Age = emplAge
        Set Create = .Self 'returns the newly created instance
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As Employee
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    this.Name = value
End Property

Public Property Get Age() As String
    Age = this.Age
End Property

Public Property Let Age(ByVal value As String)
    this.Age = value
End Property
```

With that, you can do this:

```
Dim empl As Employee
Set empl = Employee.Create("Johnny", 69)
```

`Employee.Create` is working off the *default instance*, i.e. it's considered a member of the *type*, and invoked from the default instance only.

Problem is, this is also perfectly legal:

```
Dim emplFactory As New Employee
Dim empl As Employee
Set empl = emplFactory.Create("Johnny", 69)
```

And that sucks, because now you have a confusing API. You could use `'@Description` annotations / `VB_Description` attributes to document usage, but without Rubberduck there's nothing in the editor that shows you that information at the call sites.

Besides, the `Property Let` members are accessible, so your `Employee` instance is *mutable*:

```
empl.Name = "Jane" ' Johnny no more!
```

The trick is to make your class implement an *interface* that only exposes what needs to be exposed:

[`IEmployee` class]

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Name() As String : End Property
Public Property Get Age() As Integer : End Property
```

And now you make `Employee` *implement* `IEmployee` - the final class might look like this:

[`Employee` class]

```
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit
Implements IEmployee

Private Type TEmployee
    Name As String
    Age As Integer
End Type

Private this As TEmployee

Public Function Create(ByVal emplName As String, ByVal emplAge As Integer) As IEmployee
    With New Employee
        .Name = emplName
        .Age = emplAge
        Set Create = .Self 'returns the newly created instance
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As IEmployee
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    this.Name = value
End Property

Public Property Get Age() As String
    Age = this.Age
End Property

Public Property Let Age(ByVal value As String)
    this.Age = value
End Property

Private Property Get IEmployee_Name() As String
    IEmployee_Name = Name
End Property

Private Property Get IEmployee_Age() As Integer
    IEmployee_Age = Age
End Property
```

Notice the `Create` method now returns *the interface*, and the interface *doesn't* expose the `Property Let` members? Now calling code can look like this:

```
Dim empl As IEmployee
Set empl = Employee.Create("Immutable", 42)
```

And since the client code is written against the interface, the only members `empl` exposes are the members defined by the `IEmployee` interface, which means it doesn't see the `Create` method, nor the `Self` getter, nor any of the `Property Let` mutators: so instead of working with the "concrete" `Employee` class, the rest of the code can work with the "abstract" `IEmployee` interface, and enjoy an immutable, polymorphic object.

Comment: Note: *immutable* isn't really achievable; the instance has access to its fields and can very well mutate their values. But it's better than exposing `Property Let` to the outside world (or worse, public fields!)

Comment: wouldn't the calling code be `Dim empl as Employee` since the Employee `Class` Implements `IEmployee` otherwise runtime error with the way you have it written

Comment: @Jose `Dim empl As IEmployee` works precisely *because* the class `Implements IEmployee`.

Comment: why am I getting `Variable not Defined` for `Employee.Create`?

Comment: Because you skipped the `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True` part ;-)

Comment: @Matheiu Guindon - don't mean to spam, but I am revisiting this post almost 3 months later. Since, I have been reading your rubberduck blog over and over on OOP, and this answer now makes complete sense to me. I can't believe the questions I asked in the comments above.

Comment: Great answer!  On a side note: I find it interesting that almost all devs (since Hungarian not cool) go OUT OF THEIR WAY to avoid incl. a (Const/Var/Proc/ Mod) Type name inside their Ids to the point that they'll use diff leading cap (btw, worse - idea - EVER) in case-sensitive langs to differ between Type and Var of same name or, in case-INsensitive langs, violating their own newER style of not using non-std abbrevs (like you did).  MAYbe pre-90's, i.e. pre-Auto-Complete, it was "'worth'" it, but since then, no excuse to not incl. the FULL TYPE NAME as a SUFfix.  "Code read MUCH > written."

Comment: @Tom FWIW the VBIDE autocomplete is actually still stuck in 1997, but anyway if I wrote this answer/code today (it's 5 years old), I'd probably have used `PascalCase` identifier names everywhere. I agree `empl` is a clumsy prefix, but to your point about using the full type name *as a suffix*, I'd perhaps do this for the names of related classes or different implementations of an interface, but not for a variable or a property: `empl` would be `Employee As IEmployee`, and `emplName` would be `Name`. That said your comment is.. a bit hard to read.. but thanks! ;-)

Comment: I also find it interesting they violate their own newER style of avoiding Hungarian type prefixes with Interfaces (I suspect cuz they ran out of ways to differ via capitalization since lower & upper case already used for Var and Class (sigh - face palm).  They could've stayed consistent by just using SUFfix all along (except I'll grant an exception for Vars since they're ref'ed much more often).  Code should read like spoken natural lang.  You can't *speak* diff cases.  E.g., "I can do this w/ my Employee OBJECT, cuz my Employee CLASS ...". See: https://analystcave.com/vba-implements-tutorial/

Comment: @Tom nah "Class" and "Interface" (including the "I" prefix) both have nothing to do in an identifier name, however the `I` prefix to denote an abstract interface has just about as much historical significance as using `i` for a `For` loop counter does; my style is heavily influenced by C# and .NET conventions, if my background was Java I would have argued for having a `Person` interface implemented by an `Employee` class. So happy to finally come across you, after so many years of sending people over to your awesome post about `For...Next` vs `For Each` loops!

Answer (score 2):

Using the trick

```
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
```

I found another more compact way:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
Option Compare Binary

Private v_cBox As ComboBox

'
' Class creaor
Public Function New_(ByRef cBox As ComboBox) As ComboBoxExt_c
  If Me Is ComboBoxExt_c Then
    Set New_ = New ComboBoxExt_c
    Call New_.New_(cBox)
  Else
    Set v_cBox = cBox
  End If
End Function
```

As you can see the New_ constructor is called to both create and set the private members of the class (like init) only problem is, if called on the non-static instance it will re-initialize the private member.  but that can be avoided by setting a flag.

Answer (score 1):

First, here is a very quick summary/comparison of the baseline approach and the top three answers.

**The baseline approach**: These are the basic ways to construct new instances of a class:

```
Dim newEmployee as Employee
Dim newLunch as Lunch

'==Very basic==
Set newEmployee = new Employee
newEmployee.Name = "Cam"
newEmployee.Age = 42

'==Use a method==
Set newLunch = new Lunch
newLunch.Construct employeeName:= "Cam" food:="Salad", drink:="Tea"
```

Above, `Construct` would be a sub in the Lunch class that assigns the parameter values to an object.

The issue is that even with a method, it took two lines, first to set the new object, and second to fill the parameters.  It would be nice to do both in one line.

**1) The Factory class (bgusach)**: Make a separate class ("Factory"), with methods to create instances of any other desired classes including set-up parameters.

Possible use:

```
Dim f as Factory 'a general Factory object
Dim newEmployee as Employee
Dim newLunch as Lunch

Set f = new Factory
Set newEmployee = f.CreateEmployee("Bob", 25) 
Set newLunch = f.CreateLunch(newEmployee, "Sandwich", "Soda")
```

When you type "f." in the code window, after you `Dim f as Factory`, you see a menu of what it can create via Intellisense.

**2) The Factory module (stenci)**: Same, but instead of a class, Factory can be a standard module.

Possible use:

```
Dim newEmployee as Employee
Dim newLunch as Lunch

Set newEmployee = CreateEmployee("Jan", 31) 'a function
Set newLunch = CreateLunch(newEmployee, "Pizza", "JuiceBox")
```

In other words, we just make a function outside the class to create new objects with parameters.  This way, you don't have to create or refer to a Factory object.  You also don't get the as-you-type intellisense from the general factory class.

**3) The Global Instance (Mathieu Guindon)**: Here we return to using objects to create classes, but sticking to the class-to-be-made.  If you modify the class module in an external text editor you can call class methods before creating an object.

Possible use:

```
Dim newEmployee as Employee
Dim newLunch as Lunch

Set newEmployee = newEmployee.MakeNew("Ace" 50)
Set newLunch = newLunch.MakeNew(newEmployee, "Burrito", "Water")
```

Here `MakeNew` is a function like `CreateEmployee` or `CreateLunch` in the general factory class, except that here it is in the class-to-be-made, and so we don't have to specify what class it will make.

This third approach has a fascinating "created from itself" appearance to it, permitted by the global instance.  [Edit: I should note that Matthieu takes this further to add guardrails with use of an interface.]

**Other ideas: Auto-instancing, a Clone method, or a Parent Collection Class**
With auto instancing (`Dim NewEmployee as new Employee`, note the word "new"), you can achieve something similar to the global instance without the setup process:

```
Dim NewEmployee as new Employee
NewEmployee.Construct("Sam", 21)
```

With "new" in the `Dim` statement, the NewEmployee object is created as an implied pre-step to calling its method. `Construct` is a Sub in the Employee class, just like in the baseline approach.<sup>[1]</sup>

There are some issues with auto instancing; some hate it, a few defend it.<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489507/is-the-poor-performance-of-excel-vba-auto-instancing-a-myth)</sup>  To restrict auto-instancing to one proto-object, you could add a `MakeNew` function to the class as I used with the Global Instance approach, or revise it slightly as `Clone`:

```
Dim protoEmployee as new Employee 'with "new", if you like

'Add some new employees to a collection
Dim someNames() as Variant, someAges() as Variant
Dim someEmployees as Collection
someNames = array("Cam", "Bob", "Jan", "Ace")
someAges = array(23, 45, 30, 38)
set someEmployees = new Collection

for i = 0 to 3
    someEmployees.Add protoEmployee.Clone(someNames(i), someAges(i))
next
```

Here, the `Clone` method could be set up with optional parameters `Function Clone(optional employeeName, optional employeeAge)`and use the properties of the calling object if none are supplied.

Even without auto-instancing, a `MakeNew` or `Clone` method within the class itself can create new objects in one line, once you create the proto-object.  You could use auto-instancing for a general factory object in the same way, to save a line, or not.

Finally, you might want a parent class.  A parent class could have methods to create new children with parameters (e.g., with Employees as a custom collection, `set newEmployee = Employees.AddNew(Tom, 38)`).  For a lot of objects in Excel this is standard: you can't create a Worksheet or a Workbook except from its parent collection.

<sup>[1]</sup><sub>One other adjustment relates to whether the `Construct` method is a Sub or a Function.  If `Construct` is called from an object to fill in its own properties, it can be a Sub with no return value.  However, if `Construct` returns `Me` after filling in the parameters, then the Factory methods/functions in the top 2 answers could leave the parameters to `Construct`.  For example, using a factory class with this adjustment could go: `Set Sue =  Factory.NewEmployee.Construct("Sue", "50")`, where `NewEmployee` is a method of `Factory` that returns a blank new Employee, but `Construct` is a method of `Employee` that assigns the parameters internally and returns `Me`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Adding yet another method to the fray.

The solution I propose throws a runtime error if `New SomeUserClass` is used instead of the Factory function. This way, your exposed member functions can operate knowing the object is fully initialized before its code is allowed to execute.

Basically, you can't pass arguments to a class initializer, so using code like
`somevar = New SomeUserClass("Some Initializer")` doesn't work. Using a public create function is a nice alternative to bring initializer arguments into the fold, however it still allows the use of `somevar = New SomeUserClass` without penalty. In this case, you could set an initialized flag and check for it in each function, but this is also tedious.

```
' Factory.bas

Option Explicit

Private m_globalInitializer As Variant

' This could also just be a function
Public Property Get GlobalInitializer() As Variant
    If IsEmpty(m_globalInitializer) Then _
        Err.Raise 5, , "The factory function must be used to create an instance of this class"
        ' Error #5 is 'Invalid procedure call or argument'

    ' Coerce any type of value to be returned
    If IsObject(m_globalInitializer) Then
        Set GlobalInitializer = m_globalInitializer
    Else
        GlobalInitializer = m_globalInitializer
    End If

    ' Make this getter a one-time use
    m_globalInitializer = vbEmpty
End Property

Public Function CreateSomeUserClass(ByVal somearg1 As String, _
    ByVal somearg2 As Object) As SomeUserClass

    ' You can set m_globalInitializer to anything your class initializer expects
    m_globalInitializer = Array(somearg1, somearg2)

    ' This is the only place this is allowed
    Set CreateSomeUserClass = New SomeUserClass 
End Function
```

```
' SomeUserClass.cls

Option Explicit

Private m_somevar1 As String
Private m_somevar2 As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim args() As Variant
    args = GlobalInitializer ' This clears the global initializer as well
        ' allowing other objects to be factory created

    m_somevar1 = args(0)
    Set m_somevar2 = args(1)

    ' Continue rest of initialization, including calling other factories
    ' that use the GlobalInitializer idiom.
End Sub
```

With this, if New is ever called for your class outside of the factory function, you'll get a runtime error. There is no way for anything to set the private m_globalInitializer variable prior to using New, so your initializer arguments are enforced.

Answer (score -2):

Another approach

Say you create a class clsBitcoinPublicKey

In the class module create an ADDITIONAL subroutine, that acts as you would want the real constructor to behave. Below I have named it ConstructorAdjunct.

```
Public Sub ConstructorAdjunct(ByVal ...)

 ...

End Sub

From the calling module, you use an additional statement

Dim loPublicKey AS clsBitcoinPublicKey

Set loPublicKey = New clsBitcoinPublicKey

Call loPublicKey.ConstructorAdjunct(...)
```

The only penalty is the extra call, but the advantage is that you can keep everything in the class module, and debugging becomes easier.

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, this is just like calling my "InitiateProperties" manually each time you instantiate any object, which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

Why not this way:

1. In a class module »myClass« use `Public Sub Init(myArguments)` instead of `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`
2. Instancing:
   `Dim myInstance As New myClass: myInstance.Init myArguments`