# VBA constructor not working

Tags: vba, class, oop, excel, constructor

Try to create an object with a constructor in vba, I found that answer:
[pass argument to constructor in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224113/pass-arguments-to-constructor-in-vba)

But I can not make it works. I missed something.

I use the excel 2010 vba editor. I get a "compile error, syntax error" on InitiateProperties line when I launch MacroTest(), the code here:

in **TestClass** (created with modul class):

```
Option Explicit

Private pInfo1 As String
Private pInfo2 As String

Public Sub InitiateProperties(info1 As String, info2 As String)
   pInfo1 = info1
   pInfo2 = info2
End Sub
```

in **factory** (created as modul)

```
   Set CreateTestClass = New TestClass
   CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties(info1, info2)
End Function
```

in **Module1***

```
Sub MacroTest()
   Dim myObject As TestClass
   myObject = CreateTestClass("hello", "bye")
End Sub
```

the line :

```
CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties(info1, info2)
```

appear to be red

I do not see where I m wrong, it's probably obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties info1, info2`

Comment: @Rory Ahhhh - I remember the days fondly when subs and functions were different...

Comment: Or add Call, `Call CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties(info1, info2)`

Comment: @AnthonyHorne They work the same here. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
Set CreateTestClass = New TestClass
   CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties(info1, info2)
End Function
```

With **EITHER**:

```
Set CreateTestClass = New TestClass
   CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties info1, info2 
End Function
```

**OR** this:

```
 Set CreateTestClass = New TestClass
  Call CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties(info1, info2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in other comments, you need to replace:

```
CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties(info1, info2)
```

with

```
Call CreateTestClass.InitiateProperties(info1, info2)
```

You'll also find an error in `Module1` where:

```
myObject = CreateTestClass("hello", "bye")
```

should read:

```
Set myObject = CreateTestClass("hello", "bye")
```

since you are assigning a reference to the object returned by the `CreateTestClass` factory function to `myObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ( ) I assume that info1 and info2 are passed as parameters to the function in factory and are sting values.