# Constructor in VBA - Runtime error 91 "Object variable not set"

Tags: vba, class, excel, runtime-error

I am trying to write some code in excel VBA using the Object Oriented Concept. Therefore I wanted to initialize my objects with constructors, like we usually do in Java. However I discovered that the default `Class_Initialize()` Sub that is offered in VBA does not take arguments. After searching a bit, I found that the answer for this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224113/pass-arguments-to-constructor-in-vba) proposed a pretty good alternative.

Here is a sample of my Factory Module (I Named it *Creator*):

```
Public Function CreateTool(ToolID As Integer) As cTool
    Set CreateTool = New cTool
    CreateTool.InitiateProperties (ToolID)     '<= runtime error 91 here
End Function
```

The class *cTool*:

```
Private pToolID As Integer
Private pAttributes As ADODB.Recordset 
Private pCnn As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub InitiateProperties(ToolID As Integer)
    Dim sSQL As String
    Set pCnn = connectToDB()     'A function that returns a connection to the main DB
    pToolID = ToolID
    sSQL = "SELECT Tool_ID, Status, Type, Tool_Number " _
                 & "FROM Tool  WHERE Tool_ID = " & pToolID
    pAttributes.Open sSQL, pCnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
End Sub
```

This is how I call the constructor:

```
Dim tool As cTool
Set tool = Creator.CreateTool(id)
```

My issue is that when I run the code, I get the following error:

***Run-Time error '91' :*** *Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set*

The debug highlights the `CreateTool.InitiateProperties (ToolID)` line of my `CreateTool` Function.

I know that this usually happens when someone is setting a value to an object without using the keyword `Set` but it does not seem to be my case.

Any help, advice to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't create pAttributes object in your cTool.InitateProperties.

Comment: Thank you! I never tought about checking my *cTool* class as the debugger was pointing somewhere else. Adding the line `Set pAttributes = New ADODB.Recordset` solved the issue. Thanks again for the fast reply. I will edit my post to include you answer

Comment: Don't do that. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. The Question should contain the question, and Answers should contain the answer.

Comment: Well noted @Mat'sMug . I did not notice that you already made an answer. My bad, i am still new here. I will not edit the question.

Comment: No worries - if your code works as intended now, feel free to post it (all!) on [codereview.se] for tips to make it cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not be the cause of your error, but this:

```
Public Function CreateTool(ToolID As Integer) As cTool
    Set CreateTool = New cTool
    CreateTool.InitiateProperties (ToolID)     '<= runtime error 91 here
End Function
```

Is problematic for a number of reasons. Consider:

```
Public Function CreateTool(ByVal ToolID As Integer) As cTool
    Dim result As cTool
    Set result = New cTool
    result.InitiateProperties ToolID
    Set CreateTool = result
End Function
```

Now, looking at the rest of your code, you're doing the VBA equivalent of *doing work in the constructor*, i.e. accessing database and other side-effects to constructing your object.

As [@Jules correctly identified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865442/constructor-in-vba-runtime-error-91-object-variable-not-set#comment57470316_34865442), you're accessing the unitialized object `pAttributes` inside `InitiateProperties` - that's very likely the cause of your problem.

I'd **strongly** recommend another approach - if you come from Java you *know* doing work inside a constructor is bad design... the same applies to VBA.

Get your code working, and post it all up on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com) for a full peer review.

Comment: Thank you, I will modify my code accordingly. I did not know about Code Review Stack Exchange. I will start using it more often!

Comment: @OscarAnthony Keep in mind that Code Review is a place where **working** code is reviewed and not a place to ask _how to make it work_, but rather _how to make it work_ **better**.