# How to store an array which is dynamic in an class by instantiating once

Tags: excel, vba

Using VB.NET we can store values to array or list in a class which is a public variable and using constructor. Can I do same thing using using vba

Ex:

```
class Class1
{
    public string  Variable1 { get; set; }
    public string Variable2 { get; set; }

    public List<string> List1 { get; set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        Variable1 = string.Empty;
        Variable2 = string.Empty;
        List1 = new List<string>(0);
    }
}
```

I want to replicate this in vba.

Comment: VBA classes don't have a constructor but they do have a [parameterless] `Class_Initialize` method

Comment: It's not possible to exactly replicate constructor parameters in VBA, but a factory method is commonly used. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224113/pass-arguments-to-constructor-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inserrt to your project `Class Module` (note that name of this module will be name of your class as well!):

[image]

and put this code inside it:

```
'Class1
Public Var1 As String
Public Var2 As String

Public Collection1 As Collection
' constructor
Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Var1 = ""
    Var2 = ""
    Set Collection1 = New Collection
    'MsgBox "Instance created!"
End Sub
```

Then the usage would like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Michal for your quick response.How to include array which is dynamic in this.

Comment: `Collection` in VBA is `List` equivalent.

Comment: When i tried to work with array instead of collection,program is throwing error message