# Object Module in VBA As A Container for Constant values?

Tags: vba, class, containers

I am studing VBA object module and trying to use it as an easy way of retriave objects properties.

I write the code below and would really appreciate if you could tell me if there is a better way of doing it, or if I am in the right path for write some good code.

Consider that I intend to use this on a bigger project, so I need to know if it is well written.

**Class Module Animals**

```
Option Explicit

Private pCat As New Animal
Private pDog As New Animal
Private pFish As New Animal

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  pCat.Mammal = True
  pCat.NumberOfPaws = 4
  
  pDog.Mammal = True
  pDog.NumberOfPaws = 4
  
  pFish.Mammal = False
  pFish.NumberOfPaws = 0
End Sub

Property Get Cat() As Animal
  Set Cat = pCat
End Property

Property Get Dog() As Animal
  Set Dog = pDog
End Property

Property Get Fish() As Animal
  Set Fish = pFish
End Property
```

**Class Module Animal**

```
Option Explicit

Private nPaws As Integer
Private pMammal As String

Property Get NumberOfPaws() As Integer
  NumberOfPaws = nPaws
End Property

Property Let NumberOfPaws(numPaws As Integer)
  nPaws = numPaws
End Property

Property Get Mammal() As Boolean
  Mammal = pMammal
End Property

Property Let Mammal(IsMammal As Boolean)
  pMammal = IsMammal
End Property
```

**Subroutine for testing the object modeules above**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

  Dim objAnimal As New Animals
  
  Debug.Print objAnimal.Cat.Mammal
  Debug.Print objAnimal.Cat.NumberOfPaws
  
  Debug.Print objAnimal.Dog.Mammal
  Debug.Print objAnimal.Dog.NumberOfPaws
  
  Debug.Print objAnimal.Fish.Mammal
  Debug.Print objAnimal.Fish.NumberOfPaws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use a large number of `Animal` objects, it's wise not to create a new container for them as a new object, but to use a built-in one, like `Collection`, which has list and dictionary properties. Also you can use a [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object).

It also makes sense to add the `Name` property to the `Animal` object to distinguish one object from another in the list. Additionally: you can make it convenient to create objects (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224115/15035314), as well as to display information about the object (see the procedure `PrintMe()`).

### Animal class module

```
Option Explicit

Private mName As String
Private nPaws As Integer
Private pMammal As Boolean

Public Sub InitiateProperties(Name As String, Paws As Integer, Mammal As Boolean)
    mName = Name
    nPaws = Paws
    pMammal = Mammal
End Sub

Public Sub PrintMe()
    Debug.Print "The animal is " & mName & ", it has " & nPaws & " paws(s) and is" & IIf(pMammal, " ", " not ") & "a mammal"
End Sub

Property Get Name() As Integer
  Name = mName
End Property

Property Let Name(theName As Integer)
  mName = theName
End Property

Property Get NumberOfPaws() As Integer
  NumberOfPaws = nPaws
End Property

Property Let NumberOfPaws(numPaws As Integer)
  nPaws = numPaws
End Property

Property Get Mammal() As Boolean
  Mammal = pMammal
End Property

Property Let Mammal(IsMammal As Boolean)
  pMammal = IsMammal
End Property
```

### Module1 common module

```
Option Explicit

' based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224115/15035314
Public Function CreateAnimal(Name As String, Paws As Integer, Mammal As Boolean) As Animal
    Set CreateAnimal = New Animal
    CreateAnimal.InitiateProperties Name, Paws, Mammal
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim Animals As New Collection, A As Animal
    
    Animals.Add CreateAnimal("Cat", 4, True), "Cat"
    Animals.Add CreateAnimal("Dog", 4, True), "Dog"
    Animals.Add CreateAnimal("Fish", 0, False), "Fish"
    ' and so on
    
    For Each A In Animals
        A.PrintMe
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "The cat has " & Animals("Cat").NumberOfPaws & " paws" 'get the animal from the collection by name
End Sub
```

**Running test() prints:**

```
The animal is Cat, it has 4 paws(s) and is a mammal
The animal is Dog, it has 4 paws(s) and is a mammal
The animal is Fish, it has 0 paws(s) and is not a mammal
The cat has 4 paws
```

Comment: Thanks for the repply Алексей Р. But I would like to keep the hability to call an animal property using the intellisense list. So I can use Like objAnimals.Cat.NumberOfPaws every time I need this information.