# Is VBA an OOP language, and does it support polymorphism?

Tags: excel, vba, oop, polymorphism

I am actually working on my first *VBA* project. (come from *C++*)

I would like to improve an existing *VBA* project used by a *Microsoft Excel* workbook by implementing classes and polymorphism.

**My problem is:**

**1 -** I read a lot of articles/forums which explain that *VBA* is not an Object Oriented Programming (*OOP*) language and do not support Polymorphism.

Some of them propose a workaround using the keyword **Implements**.

**2 -** I also found some webpages like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x4yd9d5(v=vs.90).aspx) which explain how to perform OOP and polymorphism in VBA using keywords like **Inherits**, **Overrides**, **Overridable**, **MustOverrides**.

**So my question is :**

Is *VBA* an *OOP* language, and does it support polymorphism ?

Comment: Point 2 is about VB, not VBA. There is no such keywords like `Inherits`, `Overrides`, `Overridable`, `MustOverrides` in VBA.

Comment: Ok, but I though VBA was VB for Application. Is is not the same base language ?

Comment: Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) is an event-driven, object-oriented programming language for writing macros, used for the entire Office suite as well as other applications.... this is a definition by [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) :). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5DImplements) some posts about ```Implements``` in VBA.

Comment: VBA is much like VB from Visual studio version 6 and older. VB now is VB.NET. Much of what is VB.NET is not in VBA.

Comment: [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Implements.aspx) good example with ```Implments```.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments. They answer to my question, and give me some ways to investigate.

Comment: One can mimic inheritance in VBA, I direct you to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669270/vba-inheritance-analog-of-super/53725027#answer-53725027)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

OOP is sitting on 4 "pillars":

- [image: check] **Abstraction** - Abstracting logic and concepts can easily be done by defining objects in *class modules*. Strictly speaking, *abstraction* is also achieved by using meaningful identifiers and extracting procedural code into methods (class members).

  Here's an example of a procedure written in VBA that demonstrates *abstraction*:

  ```
   Public Sub Test(ByVal checkin As Date, ByVal checkout As Date, ByVal custType As CustomerType)
       Dim finder As New HotelFinder
       InitializeHotels finder
       Debug.Print finder.FindCheapestHotel(checkin, checkout, custType)
   End Sub
  ```

  It's easy to tell what this `Test` procedure does at a glance, because the *abstraction level* is very high: the *implementation details* are *abstracted* away into more specialized objects and methods.
- [image: check] **Encapsulation** - Classes can have private fields exposed by properties; classes can be made `PublicNotCreatable`, effectively exposing types to other VBA projects - and with a little bit of effort (by exporting the class module, opening it in your favorite text editor, manually editing class attributes, and re-importing the module), you can achieve actual read-only types. The fact that there are no parameterized constructors is irrelevant - just write a factory method that takes all the parameters you like and return an instance. This is COM, and COM likes factories anyway.

  Here's an example of how the `HotelFinder` class from the above snippet *encapsulates* a `Collection` object and only exposes it through a `Property Get` accessor - code outside this class simply cannot `Set` this reference, it's *encapsulated*:

  ```
   Private Type TFinder
       Hotels As Collection
   End Type
   Private this As TFinder

   Public Property Get Hotels() As Collection
       Set Hotels = this.Hotels
   End Property

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       Set this.Hotels = New Collection
   End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Set this.Hotels = Nothing
   End Sub
  ```
- [image: check] **Polymorphism** - `Implements` lets you implement abstract interfaces (and concrete classes, too), and then you can write code against an `ISomething` abstraction that can just as well be a `Foo` or a `Bar` (given `Foo` and `Bar` both implement `ISomething`) - and all the code ever needs to see is `ISomething`. Method overloading is a language feature that VBA lacks, but overloading has nothing to do with polymorphism, which is *[the ability to present the same interface for differing underlying forms (data types)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism)*.

  Here's an example of applied polymorphism - the `LogManager.Register` method is happy to work with any object that implements the `ILogger` interface; here a `DebugLogger` and a `FileLogger` - two wildly different implementations of that interface, are being registered; when `LogManager.Log(ErrorLevel, Err.Description)` is invoked later, the two implementations will each do their own thing; `DebugLogger` will output to the *immediate* toolwindow, and `FileLogger` will write an entry into a specified log file:

  ```
   LogManager.Register DebugLogger.Create("MyLogger", DebugLevel)
   LogManager.Register Filelogger.Create("TestLogger", ErrorLevel, "C:\Dev\VBA\log.txt")
  ```
- [image: nope] **Inheritance** - VBA does not let you derive a type from another: inheritance is not supported.

---

Now the question is, *can a language that doesn't support inheritance be qualified as "object-oriented"?* It turns out **composition** is very often preferable to inheritance, which has a number of caveats. And VBA will let you *compose* objects to your heart's content.

> *Is VBA an OOP language?*

Given all that's missing is inheritance, and that composition is preferable to inheritance, I'm tempted to answer "Yes". I've written full-blown OOP VBA code before (Model-View-Presenter with Unit-of-Work and Repository, anyone?), that I wouldn't have written any differently in a "real OOP" language that supports inheritance.

Here are a few examples, all 100% VBA:

- [Model-View-ViewModel infrastructure & example (proof-of-concept)](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/examples/tree/master/MVVM)
- [Full-blown OOP Battleship game with Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Battleship)
- [A reusable progress indicator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87818/23788)
- [Model-View-Presenter pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58348/23788)
- [UnitOfWork with Repository pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60820/23788)
- [Polymorphic logger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64109/23788)
- [Automagic Unit Testing framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63004/23788)

The code in this last link was eventually ported to C#, and quickly evolved into [a COM add-in for the VBA IDE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/rubberduck/info) that gives you refactorings, better navigation, code inspections, and other tools.

VBA is only as limiting as you make it.

Comment: Achieving the same aim by working in a way that contradicts a definition doesn't mean that your approach is the same as the defined approach.  If OOP requires four facets and you have three of those facets plus another way to achieve something similar to the fourth facet in the long run but which is implement in a very different and more convuluted manner it doesn't mean that you have all four facets.  Exagerating to make a point: I have a petrol car, if I put diesel in it and push it somewhere it does not mean that I have a diesel car.

Comment: By the way, I'm a big fan of your Rubberduck Add-In.  A straightforward unit testing framework for VBA was a godsend, plus a project explorer that is actually useful!  I assume you switched to C# when you wanted it to be OOP :P

Comment: OOP doesn't require inheritance, it just requires polymorphism. Thanks for the complement on the project btw. We didn't switch to C# because we wanted it to be OOP, we switched to C# because it's easier to manage and *it's flavor of OOP* doesn't have the same limitations.

Comment: I've added some all-VBA examples for each point I'm making. Code doesn't get any more object-oriented than that.

Answer (score 3):

The short answers are no and no.

VBA is object based, allowing you to define classes and create instances of objects but it lacks the features that would normally be associated with a fully fledged OOP language, for example:

- Encapsulation and abstraction: VBA provides this to an extent.  Classes can be kept private with public interfaces defined, however there is no provision for constructors within classes.  Classes have a [`Class_Inititalize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/571352/4437159) event which can do some construction but cannot take arguments.  Passing arguments would require a public [factory function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224115/4437159) workarounds are still required to create a constructor-style design pattern.
- Inheritance: Doesn't really exist in VBA but can be  [almost replicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671434/4437159)
- Polymorphism: Can be achieved to an extent through interfaces (using `Implements`) although the ability to overload functions (for example) doesn't exist and each "overload" would technically require a unique function name.  You can work around this by passing in an object as the only parameter to a function or sub and vary the procedure depending on the values of the properties.

So while you can work with objects to an extent and MS Office applications are based around an object model, VBA is not truely an Object Oriented language.  Polymorphism cannot be achieved to the extent that you would be familiar with in C++.

Comment: VBA may not support inheritance, but it does support [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) which is a different means to the same end in many ways.

Comment: I would be tempted to argue that VBA is, in fact, an Object Oriented language by most definitions, but which omits many of the common features that people are used to in robust OO languages like Java or C#.

Comment: @Blackhawk I dunno, it doesn't even provide inheritance, I'd argue that that was a fundemental requirement to be object oriented.  I would probably stick with an object based language that supports some object oriented features.

Comment: It seems to me that the purpose of inheritance in OOP is to function as re-use and polymorphism. Composition and interfaces are another way of achieving the same thing, and in fact are sometimes the better choice (see the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)). I would agree that re-use and polymorphism are necessary for OOP and VBA has them. See the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles of OOP and compare them against VBA functionality.

Comment: All that being said, if VBA is OOP, it's definitely the bastard step-child of OO languages.

Comment: @Blackhawk sorry, I just realised the order of my hyperlinks was a shambles.  The link i had intended to attach to inheritance was essentially showing composition anyway.  I can see why it would be favourable in some cases although it's a bit tedious if you only need to override 1 out of 100 funcitons.

Comment: Yeah, but if you literally need to override 1 out of 100 functions, you should probably keep just the single class but design it to swap out implementations with the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This discussion could go back and forth all day :P I think the takeaway for anyone reading these comments is: Is inheritance necessary for OOP or are reuse and polymorphism enough?

Comment: You have a decent answer here, except you start off by saying "No. It's not an OOP language and no, it doesn't support polymorphism", but it certainly *does* support polymorphism. IMO it's OOP too, but I can see where it's debatable because "it's definitely the bastard step-child of OO languages".