# VBA Display Collection in a message box - error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Pop-up a message something like,

```
"There are 3 Reports available . They are Today, Yesterday, Day before"
```

This is the code,

```
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each a In MonthYear
     arr.Add a, a
  Next

  For i = 1 To arr.Count
     Cells(i, 1) = arr(i)
  Next


MsgBox ("There are " & arr.Count & " Reports available. They are  " & arr &
```

But it is not working. It says sub or argument not found.

Comment: You have to specify which element of array you want in `& arr &`. As you want to list them all you need to have a loop that builds it.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is a nice way to shoot yourself in the foot when attempting to debug code. Actually, it's a nice way to shoot yourself in the foot in debugged production code except when used in a _very_ controlled manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim arr     As Variant
    arr = Array("Today", "Yesterday", "DayBefore")

    MsgBox ("There are " & UBound(arr) + 1 & _
            " reports available. They are " & Join(arr, ", ") & ".")


End Sub
```

Concerning the collection this is one way to transfer the collection to a string:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe2()

    Dim reportsCol  As New Collection
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim textReport  As String

    reportsCol.Add "Today"
    reportsCol.Add "Yesterday"
    reportsCol.Add "The day before yesterday"

    For i = 1 To reportsCol.Count
        textReport = TextReport & " " & reportsCol(i) & _
            IIf(i = reportsCol.Count, ".", ",")
    Next i

    MsgBox textReport

End Sub
```

The `IIf` at the bottom decides whether to put a full stop `.` or a comma `,`.

Comment: This will work if arr is an array. But in my case, it is a collection.

Comment: @Sid29 for the love of everything that's good in this world, **please** rename that variable to something meaningful, e.g. `reportColumns`. And [**drop *Systems Hungarian* notation**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I suppose that you mean me and not Sid?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes sir, will do :) It is so confusing. I started building it as an array and then just changed it to collection, that's why.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - ok, I will edit it here. But in general, once I started like this it is tough to change. My code will become inconsistent.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - now you only need to know a certain boss, who does not allow additional software used in the company and everything will come to its place.

Comment: If your IT folks / programmers have tooling such as ReSharper or they're using Visual Studio, that certain boss is unfairly blocking your productivity.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - true, but "the programmers are programmers and I am writing on that funny scripting language that does not even compile" (these are real  words, that I have heard about 4 years ago in a German company. I always laugh when I remember it! :)

Comment: @Vityata oh FFS... he's mistaking VBA for VBScript. WTF does he think 'Debug' -> 'Compile' do?!

Comment: @Mat'sMug will definitely look into that. Thanks:-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - he meant VBA and he meant compiling the way C# does.

Comment: Wow, what a hopeless ignorant jerk. [VBA is a perfectly fine OOP-capable COM-based language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861832/1188513) and FWIW it's a hosted version of VB6, running with the very same VM. And VB6 was the "funny scripting language" everyone was using to compile executables and type libraries 15 years ago. The VM runs p-code, VBA compiles to p-code, and p-code is the pre-.NET equivalent of MSIL or Java's bytecode. This loser has no clue what he's talking about.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - true but he had his own way of understanding computers... That's why I have separated VBA from the other languages here -
 http://vitoshacademy.com/about

Comment: @Mat'sMug - cheer up, it will appear in the near future :)

Answer (score 6):

For an array, as it appeared that the OP was using one.  Now that the OP has editted the post to show a collection this method will not work.

I will leave it for future readers for an option with arrays.

```
MsgBox "There are " & UBound(arr) + 1 & " Reports available. They are  " & Join(arr,",")
```

Comment: It skips over that part actually. The message box is not popping up.

Comment: It is declared as a collection. My bad. Extremely sorry.