# Can I make methods visible to some classes but not others

Tags: vba, excel, scope

Quite simple; I've made a class with a method that's public since another class calls this method.

I would like the method only to show up on intellisense in the 2nd class which holds some special reference to the 1st one. Any other class or module should not be able to see the method.

Something along the lines of

```
Semi-Private (except for Class2) Sub ...
```

in the method of Class1, or in Class2

```
Can See Semi-Private methods of Class1
```

Comment: "I've made a class with a method that's public since another class calls this method." - it would be helpful to give the code for this one.

Comment: I usually like the idea of small classes, but it sounds like `Class1` and `Class2` are tightly coupled. Perhaps the methods could be moved into 1 class, then just make the "semi-private" methods `private`. It would improve cohesion.

Comment: If moving things to 1 class is painful, you should probably leave the methods public. What harm can it cause?

Comment: The [friend access modifier](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx) limits accessibility to calls from within the same workbook.  Not sure if that helps here.

Comment: @destination-data That would only prevent other projects from using the class, and not other modules or classes from using the class.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting complicated with it, and using a roundabout approach, just use the tools meant for the job:

**Class Module IFoo**

```
Public Sub Bar()
    ' Interface methods are empty
End Sub
```

**Class Module Foo**

```
Private Type TFoo
    Baz As String
End Type

Private this As TFoo

Implements IFoo

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    this.Baz = "I am a class that implements IFoo."
End Sub

Private Sub IFoo_Bar()
    ' Do Something
    Debug.Print this.Baz
End Sub
```

**Module Baz**

```
Sub RunBaz()
    Dim MyFoo As IFoo

    ' Note that this WILL NOT work. Nothing happens.
    Set MyFoo = New IFoo
    Debug.Print MyFoo.Bar

    ' Set MyFoo to be equal to a Foo (which implements IFoo)
    Set MyFoo = New Foo
    Debug.Print MyFoo.Baz
End Sub
```

This makes the methods only visible when the methods are being accessed through an interface which makes them public. Therefore, in order to use the methods in `Foo` we must first create an instance of `Foo` using an `IFoo` variable type.

Then, it is as simple as creating a new class which creates a `Foo` from an `IFoo` for its own use.

**Class Module IImportantWorker**

```
Public Sub DoSomethingImportant()

End Sub
```

**Class Module ImportantWorker**

```
Private Type TImportantWorker
    Implementation As IFoo
End Type

Private this As TImportantWorker

Implements IImportantWorker

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Implementation = New Foo
End Sub

Public Sub IImportantWorker_DoSomethingImportant()
    this.Implementation.Bar
End Sub
```

You could get fancy from here and make a property of Foo that is exposed by `IFoo` that tells it whether or not it can work. This would have to be exposed through the IFoo interface (or, alternatively a separate interface so that the two interfaces must be used in conjunction).

Without *locking* the class (which I wouldnt recommend anyways, it seems foolish and pointless) `Foo` will still allow `Bar` if it is created as a `IFoo`. But if you just make `Foo = New Foo` then `Foo` will do nothing (or rather, expose nothing).

For additional resources, I highly recommend reading these excellent posts that go into greater depth about the processes:

[Is VBA an OOP language, and does it support polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858094/is-vba-an-oop-language-and-does-it-support-polymorphism/31861832#31861832)

https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/oop-vba-pt-1-debunking-stuff/

https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/oop-vba-pt-2-factories-and-cheap-hotels/

Answer (score 0):

You may create the class that contains all properties and methods, name it BigClass:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i1 As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim i3 As Integer


Property Let var1(v As Integer)
    i1 = v
End Property

Property Get var1() As Integer
    var1 = i1
End Property

Property Let var2(v As Integer)
    i2 = v
End Property

Property Get var2() As Integer
    var2 = i2
End Property

Property Let var3(v As Integer)
    i3 = v
End Property

Property Get var3() As Integer
    var3 = i3
End Property
```

Then you can make classes that inherits BigClass methods, but not necessary all of them. For example, SmallClass1 that will use only var3 variable.

```
Option Explicit

Dim BigOne As BigClass

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set BigOne = New BigClass
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set BigOne = Nothing
End Sub

Property Let var3(v As Integer)
    BigOne.var3 = v
End Property

Property Get var3() As Integer
    var3 = BigOne.var3
End Property
```

Then you can create SmallClass2 that use var2 and var1 but not var3. You get the point.

Comment: But shouldn't you in `SmallClass1` hand `var3` through to the `BigOne` like let `BigOne.var3 = v` and get `var3 = BigOne.var3`? Otherwise this makes not much sense or am I completely wrong?

Comment: You are right, just edited my answer. Anyway, my proposal is to have class that contains all properties and function and class that creates object of the first class and use some of the properties and functions.

Comment: I would avoid the word `Inherit` since VBA doesn't support `Inheritance` and your example is instead exposing members through its own methods, but not inheriting the class. The distinction being that if I add `Sub Foo` to `BigClass` I must also add `Sub Foo` to `SmallClass`.

Answer (score 0):

An clear example would be involved and lengthy and I have deposited one on my blog here [VBA - Difference between Friend and Public with inter project references.](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-difference-between-friend-and.html)

Essentially you use the Friend keyword but nothing happens until you split your code across workbooks which itself brings issues such as Instancing and factory functions.  Example given should work though.  Enjoy!