# Order of functions (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Perhaps this is a straightforward question, but I need to 100% verify this. I have a function (Execute) that calls different modules in order.. Like this:

```
Private Sub Execute()
Call Func1
Call Func2
Call Func3
End Sub
```

Functions 1 and 2 are quite complicated functions that draws and manipulates data. What is very important is that functions 1 and 2 are executed **and completed** prior to running function 3.

One way I do this currently is by forcing a 1 second lag prior function 3 to ensure 1 and 2 are finished, something like this:

```
Private Sub Execute()
Call Func1
Call Func2
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Call Func3
End Sub
```

I am thinking of removing the 1 second lag - but I really want to make sure that functions are running and completing in a synchronized manner.

Thanks

Comment: VBA is single threaded so there is no need for the `.Wait()`. What a wonderful thing it would be if we could run parallel though.

Comment: You see, I am loading and manipulating huge amounts from SQL to Excel in Functions 1 and 2. I need to make sure that it is all complete and loaded before attempting function 3.. Do you know what I mean? I do not want data still loading in memory while attempting to run func 3.

Comment: One caution is if you are using Power Query in one of those functions. VBA doesn't wait for PQ by default. You can force it; (backgroundRefresh = False, Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone, etc.)

Comment: Luckily I do not use Power Query. I only use ADODB for SQL Server connections and standard functions in Excel & VBA.

Comment: Drop the `Call` keyword, it's redundant, useless and obsolete. Also if none of your `Function` procedures return anything, they should probably be `Sub` procedures instead. Lastly, the parentheses around the argument list in the `Application.Wait` call (why is there no `Call` on that one?! Gotta love the consistency of `Call` proponents), are force-evaluating `Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")` as a value, and force-passing the result `ByVal`. If this extraneous parentheses thing is a habit, you'll inevitably run into "Object Required" errors caused by it.

Comment: Also see if the [temporal coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50743044/1188513) can be removed by eliminating global state and introducing parameters. That said, VBA is single-threaded and, unless you're writing event-driven code, completely synchronous - unless you're invoking an API that is documented as asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty certain that VBA function calls would be synchronous, but one easy way you could verify this would be to put `debug.print` statements inside your functions. In `Func1` put `debug.print "Entering Func1"` as the very first statement and `debug.print "Exiting Func1"` as the very last statement. Put equivalent statements in the other two functions. After you run your `Execute` function, examine the debug window to check that all the messages come out in the expected order.